# Solving for all valid inputs with an ATS

Tags: smt, equation-solving, theorem-proving

Let's say you have a system of pure expressions, like,

```
(bi0, bi1, bi2, ai0, ai1, ai2) := inputs
b0 := bi0 && bi1
a1 := b0 ? ai0 : cbrt(ai0)
a2 := bi2 ? a1 : ai1
output := a2 > ai2

# prove:
output == True
```

Can an automated theorem prover be programmed, not just to find some `inputs` for which `output` is true, but to find all possible `inputs` for which it is true?

Answer (score 0):

SMT solvers are quite good at solving these sorts of constraints and there are many to choose from. See https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu for an overview.

One implementation is Microsoft's z3, which can easily handle queries like the one you posed: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3

SMT solvers can be programmed in the so called SMTLib syntax (see first link above), or they provide APIs in many languages for you to program them in; including C/C++/Java/Python/Haskell etc. Furthermore, most theorem provers these days (including Isabelle/HOL) come with tactics that use these provers behind the scenes; so many integrations are possible.

As I mentioned, z3 can be programmed in various languages, a good paper to review is [https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html), which uses Python to do so.

### A Solution using Z3 in Haskell

For your particular problem, here's how it'd be solved using z3 in Haskell, using the SBV layer (http://leventerkok.github.io/sbv/):

```hs
import Data.SBV

problem :: IO AllSatResult
problem = allSatWith z3{allSatPrintAlong = True} $ do
            [bi0, bi1, bi2] <- sBools ["bi0", "bi1", "bi2"]
            [ai0, ai1, ai2] <- sReals ["ai0", "ai1", "ai2"]

            cbrt_ai0 <- sReal "cbrt_ai0"
            let cube x = x * x * x
            constrain $ cube cbrt_ai0 .== ai0

            let b0 = bi0 .&& bi1
                a1 = ite b0  ai0 cbrt_ai0
                a2 = ite bi2 a1  ai1

            pure $ a2 .> ai2
```

When I run this, I get:

```
*Main> problem
Solution #1:
  bi0      = False :: Bool
  bi1      = False :: Bool
  bi2      = False :: Bool
  ai0      = 0.125 :: Real
  ai1      =  -0.5 :: Real
  ai2      =  -2.0 :: Real
  cbrt_ai0 =   0.5 :: Real
Solution #2:
  bi0      = True :: Bool
  bi1      = True :: Bool
  bi2      = True :: Bool
  ai0      =  0.0 :: Real
  ai1      =  0.0 :: Real
  ai2      = -1.0 :: Real
  cbrt_ai0 =  0.0 :: Real
Solution #3:
  bi0      =  True :: Bool
  bi1      = False :: Bool
  bi2      =  True :: Bool
  ai0      =   0.0 :: Real
  ai1      =   0.0 :: Real
  ai2      =  -1.0 :: Real
  cbrt_ai0 =   0.0 :: Real

...[many more lines deleted...]
```

I interrupted the output since it seems there's a lot of assignments (possibly infinite by looking at the structure of your problem).

### A solution using Z3 in Python

Another popular choice is to use Python to program the same. The code is a bit more verbose than Haskell in this case, there's some boiler-plate to get all-solutions and other Python gotchas, but otherwise follow a similar path:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

bi0, bi1, bi2 = Bools('bi0 bi1 bi2')
ai0, ai1, ai2 = Reals('ai0 ai1 ai2')

cbrt_ai0 = Real('cbrt_ai0')

def cube(x):
    return x*x*x

s.add(cube(cbrt_ai0) == ai0)

b0 = And(bi0, bi1)
a1 = If(b0, ai0, cbrt_ai0)
a2 = If(bi2, a1, ai1)

s.add(a2  > ai2)

def all_smt(s, initial_terms):
    def block_term(s, m, t):
        s.add(t != m.eval(t, model_completion=True))
    def fix_term(s, m, t):
        s.add(t == m.eval(t, model_completion=True))
    def all_smt_rec(terms):
        if sat == s.check():
           m = s.model()
           yield m
           for i in range(len(terms)):
               s.push()
               block_term(s, m, terms[i])
               for j in range(i):
                   fix_term(s, m, terms[j])
               yield from all_smt_rec(terms[i:])
               s.pop()...
    yield from all_smt_rec(list(initial_terms))

for model in all_smt(s, [ai0, ai1, ai2, bi0, bi1, bi2]):
    print(model)
```

Again, when run this continuously spits out solutions.